# jquery dynatree array function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of functions and also I am using a dynatree plugin inside it.

Example:

```
fn1: function(){ 
   .....
}),
fn2: function(){ 
   .....
}),
fn3: { param1: xValue, param2: yValue }
```

Now I would like to add a function in fn3 like,

```
fn3: fn3a

//In fn3a
function fn3a(){
    //Based on condition add values.
    if...
        param1: xValue, param2: yValue
    else...
       param1: xValue, param2: zValue
}
```

How can I define those params in {...} in function.

Please suggest. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's OK to anonymize your code but at least post working code please. It is very difficult to understand from what little code you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know if this is what you're looking for, but maybe it's a start:

```
var funcs = {
  /* ...  others functions ... */
  fn3: { param1: 2, param2: 3 }
};


funcs.fn3 = (function (/*the old object*/ oldValue){
  /*
    ... private variable scope here, which will be accessible by the returned
    function only! ...
  */

  /* do stuff with the old values and store the values in private scope */
  var
    param1 = oldValue.param1 * oldValue.param1,
    param2 = oldValue.param2 * oldValue.param2;

  /* return a new function */
  return function () {
    /* the new return value */
    return param1 + '/' + param2;
  };
}(/*pass the old object*/ funcs.fn3));


// debug output:
console.log(funcs.fn3()); // => 4/9
```

Comment: Hey Yoshi, Thanks for reply. Yes I am looking for this kind. But in the code you suggested, I need fn3: { param1: 'some x value', param2: 'some y value' } to be replaced with fn3: fn3a and those params to be called in fn3a

Comment: Let me get this straight: You have `{ param1 ...}` code defined, and want to completely replace it, at runtime, with a new function, which has access to those values?